# Semi circle progress bar not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

Could anyone advise why my semi-circle progress bar is not working properly in different mobiles model;
It tried it in Lenovo Android 4.4.2 and working fine as shown first in pic.
But in Asus Android 5.0.2 is not working fine as show in second pic

[image]
   [image]

**Activity XML:**

```
<ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressWheel"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="175sp"
                android:max="133"
                android:progress="100"
                android:secondaryProgress="0"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ciruclar_progress_bar" />
```

**Drawable xml:**

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="135"
        android:toDegrees="135"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" >
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="20.0" >
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#44000000"
                android:endColor="#44000000"
                android:startColor="#44000000"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="135"
        android:toDegrees="135"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" >
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="25.0" >
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:type="sweep" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Comment: this may help you :   <shape
                android:useLevel="true"... </shape>